# garbage collection for class with static constructor

Tags: .net, oop, garbage-collection

Static fields are initiatlized in a static constructor.

Since static fields are considered roots and they belong to a class - how is the garbage collection done? Is one instance of the class always in memory for the lifetime of the application?

Comment: Since they are considered roots, they don't require any instance to be kept in memory, roots are just that, roots. All static fields are roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory associated with static fields are not tied to a particular instance, so they will remain in memory until the defining assembly is unloaded.